# Rest Assured :- Getting 404 response from Post request created using Pathparam and FormParam

Tags: rest-assured

I am a newbie to Rest Assured and need your help on the following issue.

I want to trigger a POST request which is as follows:-

```
Response resp = RestAssured.given().pathParam("build", bulid).
            formParam("file", "https://unsplash.com/photos/Bcv4wZSMtIA").// Cast
            formParam("type", "front").
            formParam("auto_start", false).
            then().post("https://example.com/{build}");
```

Where build= abc/xyz

Thus. should result in https://example.com/abc/xyz as endpoint and body as:

```
{   
"file" : "https://unsplash.com/photos/Bcv4wZSMtIA",
"type" : "front",
"auto_start" : false
```

}

But when triggered it gives 404, whereas when instead of using pathparam I hardcode the value of build in post request then it works fine.

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the url was being encoded when sent as request uri which when disabled using used urlEncodingEnabled(false) resolved my issue.